# Validate selected item is a possible value in drop down list

Tags: vb.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view model for editing a users settings. One of its properties is defined as

```
<Display(Name:="View_User_Profile_Language", ResourceType:=GetType(Resources.UIText))>
Public Property Language As String
```

And in the view, I use it like this:

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.UserInfoForm.Language) %>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.UserInfoForm.Language,
                 languages.Select(Function(lang) New SelectListItem With {
                     .Text = New Globalization.CultureInfo(lang).NativeName,
                     .Value = lang,
                     .Selected = (Model.UserInfoForm.Language = lang)
                 }))%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.UserInfoForm.Language)%>
```

Where `languages` is a list of strings defined in the view e.g. "en", "fr", "de"

---

The problem is that the user can submit a value that is not inside the drop down list (e.g. with javascript, inspect element or not use a browser e.g. fiddler)

How do you validate the selected item, ensuring that it exists in the drop down list?

I am aware of validation attributes such as `<StringLength>` and `<Required>`, and I use `If ModelState.IsValid Then` in the action. Is there a ready made attribute stating where the validator should look for a list of allowed values?

Thanks for reading

Comment: What defines the list of languages available in the first place? If you're generating it on the client, consider sourcing it from the server anyways (depending on your use case). Then you have validation options available when they submit.

Answer (score 0):

To do this validation on the server side in an automated validation way is not possible becasuse the server would have to remember what options were in the dropdownlists between posts. Once the dropdown list has been sent to the html output, you loose the available dropdownlist data. Thus, you need to re-create the available options one the server side to check them.

In my project, we tend to do this kind of check for correctness inside the database. In this example, they would be trying to insert a value into a field that should be linked by foreign key. In this exapmple this field would be Language, and would be a foreign key to the reference table LanugageAbbreviations. Since there is no foreign key for a selected value "zz", the database should fail when it tries to insert.

If you must push it the validation further up, you can always check the drop downs for a valid value in a method ie.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(AnimalViewModel model){
     CheckLanguageDropDownList(model, ModelState)
     ... 
 }
```

where CheckLanguageDropDownList is

```
 private void CheckLanguageDropDownList(WordsModel viewModel, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
 {
        HashSet<String> validValues = new HashSet<string>(dataLayer.LanugageAbbreviationsRefrenceTable.GetActiveValues());
        if !validValues.Contains(viewModel.Lanuage)
            modelState.AddModelError("Invalid Language ","The language selected is invalid");
 }
```

If you need to do it this way, make sure to refactor in a way that would make sense.